# A confusion about the porter stemming algorithm

Tags: c++, nlp, porter-stemmer

I am trying to implement porter stemming algorithm, but I stumbled at this point

> where the square brackets denote
>   arbitrary presence of their contents.
>   Using (VC){m} to denote VC repeated m
>   times, this may again be written as
>
> ```
> [C](VC){m}[V].
> ```
>
> m will be called the \measure\ of any
>   word or word part when represented in
>   this form. The case m = 0 covers the
>   null word. Here are some examples:
>
> ```
> m=0    TR,  EE,  TREE,  Y,  BY.
> m=1    TROUBLE,  OATS,  TREES,  IVY.
> m=2    TROUBLES,  PRIVATE,  OATEN,  ORRERY.
> ```

I don't understand what is this "measure" and what does it stand for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the measure is the number of times a vowel is immediately followed by a consonant.  For example,

"TROUBLES" has:

Optional initial consonants `[C]` = "TR".

First vowels-consonants group `(VC)` = "OUBL".

Second vowels-consonants group `(VC)` = "ES".

Optional ending vowels `[V]` is empty.

So the measure is two, the number of times `(VC)` was "matched".